# Is there a way to share a common configuration [with a config file / etc] for a maven plugin between modules?

Tags: maven

I've got a multi-module maven project that is outputting 2 different versions of an RPM. They are very similar except a few files, and the de.dentrassi.maven RPM plugin's configurations will look exactly the same.

I'm looking to see if there is any way I can put the configuration in a .conf file or something and use that so I don't have to edit the configuration in both modules each time we need to make a change.

I'm currently trying to import the configuration but I don't see any viable options/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your multi-module project probably has a common parent pom.

You can either define the plugin there (with all configuration) - this makes sense if the plugin does not "harm" other modules.

Alternatively, you define the configuration of the plugin in the `<pluginManagement>` section of the parent pom. Then you only need to define (not configure) the plugin in the relevant modules.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing is to define the configuration which is common for all execution in a configuration block looks like this:

```
<project..>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>..</groupId>
          <artifactId>..</artifactId>
          <version>1.0</version>
          <configuration>
            .. Global Configuration which is common for everything
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

So the above should/could be done in your parent pom file of your multi module build. Now in a module which inherits from the parent you can configure it like this:

```
<project..>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>..</groupId>
        <artifactId>..</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>special-exec1</id>
            <goals>..</goals
            <phase>..</phase>
            <configuration>
             ... supplemental configuration which is not part of the parent
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

So this will define the common configuration in the parent via the `pluginManagement` and each specialisation can be done in the child.

If you like to overwrite configuration or enhance parts of it this can be done like the following:

```
<project..>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>..</groupId>
        <artifactId>..</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>special-exec1</id>
            <goals>..</goals
            <phase>..</phase>
            <configuration>
              <items combine.children="append">
                 <!-- combine.children="merge" is the default -->
                <item>child-1</item>
              </items>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

All the details can be read in the [POM documentation](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html) search for `combine.children`. It is also possible to prevent the inheritance of the configuration from the parent if you need to see also the previously mentioned documentation.